# How can I run single Kotlin file in android studio like Java class?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
     var name = "Vijay"
  println("Welcome $name")
```

}

Basically, I am learning Kotlin language for my project so I want to test and run function, variable, coroutine and run some data structure programme. But whenever I ran the program, the android studio throw the
 **error: Test.kt file not found in module 'app'**.

Comment: Did you name your function `main`?

Comment: I did that, Sorry for a wrong code snippet

Answer (score 2):

While, perhaps, not a direct answer to your question, I can think of two ways to achieve what I believe you are trying to achieve:

1. Use the Kotlin REPL.  Tools > Kotlin > Kotlin REPL.  You can paste nearly anything you want, in there, and run it.
2. A second possibility: Use Studio's Scratch file capability.  Create a scratch file as shown below, put your code into it, and run it.[image: ScratchFile]